# How to avoid multiple joining the same table?

Tags: sql, mariadb

GROUPS

```
id team1_id team2_id
1     1       2
2     3       1
```

TEAMS

```
id  name
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
```

Is it possible to avoid the multiple join without changing schema or must the schema change to improve this? There will only ever be 2 teams per group.

Expected :

```
id team1_name team2_name
1     aaa       bbb
2     ccc       aaa
```

Comment: I see no query with "multiple join"s so I have no idea what your question is about.

Comment: Why would joining a table twice be a bad thing, in your opinion?

Comment: I.m.h.o., if it's only 2 left joins to a reference table like TEAMS, then that's perfectly fine on most occasions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid multiple joins is to do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    g.id,
    max(case when t.id = g.team1_id then t.name end) team1_name,
    max(case when t.id = g.team2_id then t.name end) team2_name
from groups g
inner join teams t on t.id in (g.team1_id, g.team2_id)
group by g.id
```

While this makes it easier to extend the query if new columns are added to the `groups` table, this is actually not guaranteed to perform better than the join solution. This would depend on the distribution of yuour data. If performance matters to you, you would need to test both solutions against your real data.

Another key difference with the join solution is that this query does not actually ensure that the team ids that are part of the `groups` table are all available in the `teams` table (you would need to add an `having` clause to implement this). Depending on your use case, this might, or might not be what you want.

Comment: Interesting exercise, but the big question remains: what problem does this solve? I would be _really_ surprised if this would ever outperform multiple joins in a production environment. I also didn't see how this would make it easier to extend the query if new columns were added to the `groups` table; can you give an example?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') team1_name,
    max(case when t.id = g.team2_id then g.name) team2_name

Comment: @Ramki: I fixed the syntax error (missing keywords `end` at the end of the `case` expressions).

Comment: Please elaborate on the downvote. Doesn't this query produce the correct result and answers the question that was asked?

Comment: can you please explain whats that query doing ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       Select id, max(case when 
       g.id=t.team1_id then
       g.name end), 
       max(case when 
       g.id=t.team2_id then
       g.name end)

      From groups g right join
     Teams t on
     g.id=t.id
```